# Spring 3.0 cannot get custom Annotation at runtime

Tags: java, spring, annotations, runtime, spring-3

I am working with spring and tried to add a custom Annotation to an Entity-Bean.
All I want to do is, accessing the fields with the custom annotation @ runtime via reflection.
The Problem is, that although there are more than one Annotation on the fields, none of them are accessable at runtime:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface ChangeableField {

}
```

The entity:

```
public class Order {

    @NotNull
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd:MM:yyyy HH:mm")
    @ChangeableField
    private Date scheduledStart;

    @NotNull
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd:MM:yyyy HH:mm")
    @ChangeableField
    private Date scheduledEnd;

    //...
}
```

I have absolutely no idea what to do

```
Order.class.getField("scheduledStart").getAnnotation(ChangableField.class);
```

returns always null. (BTW all declared annotations on this field are null)

Maybe it has something to do with spring?

I would appreciate any help!

Thanks in advance

### EDIT

I don't know why but now it's working properly:

```
for (Field currentField : order.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
    if (currentField.getAnnotation(ChangeableField.class) != null
    && map.containsKey(currentField.getName())) {
         //..
```

Thanks for your help

BTW It was just a typo in this post here..

Comment: Do you use 'Order.class.getField' statement for sure? Because if you're using a object.getClass() where 'object' is a Spring bean then it wouldn't work because 'object' is a proxy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your annotation is of class "ChangeableField", but you are retrieving "ChangableField" (note the missing "e").  Is this just a typo in the post, or are you not retrieving what you think you are ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Order.class
     .getDeclaredField("scheduledStart")
     .getAnnotation(ChangableField.class);
```

[`Class.getField(fieldname)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getField%28java.lang.String%29) retrieves public fields of the class and all super classes. Your field is private, so you need [`Class.getDeclaredField(fieldname)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField%28java.lang.String%29), which retrieves fields of all visibilities, but limited to this class only.

Comment: Shouldn't that have resulted in a "NoSuchFieldException" ?

Comment: @andypandy yes, I was wondering about that as well. But without seeing the actual client code we don't know which exceptions were caught